# Excel VBA to change dropdown menu within a form

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

I tried some alternatives, but with no success, to change the combobox you can find the website code below (It looks that the problem is that the combobox is inside a form - I can't change an input box as well):

```html
<form action="procRelLmPorData.asp" method="post" target="ifrmGerar" id="frmGerar" name="frmGerar">
<input type="hidden" name="ordem" id="ordem" value="" />

<table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th class="header">Licenças Médicas por Data</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="border-bottom:#048282 thin solid;width:100%;">    
<tr>
<td style="width:20%;vertical-align:top;">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Regional: </td>
  <td>
   <select style="width:200px" name="regional" id="regional" onchange="comboFilial(this.value);comboSetor('');">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
     <option value='67'>RJ</option>
    </select>
```

I've tried the codes below to solve it:

Assuming that `objie = InternetExplorer.Application`

1st - 
`objie.Document.forms("frmGerar").getElementsByTagName("select")("regional").Value = 67`

2nd -  `objie.Document.forms("frmGerar").Item("regional").Value = 67`

3rd - `objie.Document.getElementById("regional").selectedindex= 2`

Can you figure what's the problem?

EDIT

---

I've found that the form is inside an IFrame, you can find the code below:

```html
<iframe name="ifrmCentro" id="ifrmCentro" src="mapPath.asp?codMenu=404" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 177px; display: block;"></iframe>
```

Comment: i don't think this is VBA related

Comment: Yes it is. In fact I made it happen and will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I made it.

The problem was the iFrame, which I had to navigate through.

```
.Navigate Website & "mapPath.asp?codMenu=404"

Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
```

After that I could fill the boxes and select combobox:

```
.Document.all("datInicial").Value = Range("A6").Text
.Document.all("datFinal").Value = Range("A7").Text
.Document.all("regional").Value = 67
```

Thanks!